# Thunderbird pop-up notifications?

Tags: thunderbird, notification, mail-notification

I have Thunderbird set up so that I will receive a notification when I get an email, but all I get is the sound notification. Is there any way I can get a pop up with a preview of the message like I can with other email clients?

Edit: I am also using Thunderbird 41 on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Same case here, using Thunderbird 41.0 on Ubuntu 15.10 with Unity desktop. What version of Thunderbird and Ubuntu and which desktop environment do you use? You should [edit] your question to add that information. Thank you!